# Is it safe to attach a method to String if you delete it after using it?

Tags: javascript, prototype

I'm just breaking into Node.js and CommonJS modules and I am *trying* to extend the String object without littering the rest of my app and provide a clean looking method.

I was wondering, is it ok to attach a method to the global String object and then at the bottom of the file, `delete` it?

For example:

```
// hasCondition.js

String.prototype.has = function(regex) {
    return regex.test(this);
};
exports.removeMethod = function () {
    delete String.prototype.has;
};
```

.

```
// someFile.js

var has = require('./hasCondition');
console.log(  "foo bar baz".has(/baz/)  );
has.removeMethod();
console.log(  "foo bar baz".has(/baz/)  );

>>> true
>>> Object foo bar baz has no method 'has'
```

Comment: Appending prototype functions to built-in objects (other than `Object` itself) is usually fine. The only code that will break is poorly written code. See [Extending built-in native objects. Evil or not?](http://perfectionkills.com/extending-built-in-native-objects-evil-or-not/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to clutter the String space, you can make a new Object, prototyped from a String. Then, assign that object the `has` method in its prototype. It won't propagate back to String.

This way, you encapsulate that. Sure, you add another indirection layer, but it's already a [design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern).

If you aret jus worried about `has` being kept somewhere later, it won't probably be.
Even if you produce sub-objects from String with the added `has` method, when it gets removed, so will it from any inheritance.

Example of that (let us assume assert is defined):

```
function Str1() {}
Str1.prototype = new String()
String.prototype.has = function(t) { /* code here */ }
var x = new Str1()
assert(x.has)

function Str2() {}
Str2.prototype = new Str1()

var y = new Str2()
assert(y.has)

delete String.prototype.has

assert(typeof x.has === "undefined")
assert(typeof y.has === "undefined")
```

Comment: Thanks!! Your info is perfect. I need to get around to reading that JavaScript Patterns book =) I guess I was worried that someone elses plugin/module would get loaded and one of the .has methods would get clobbered.

Comment: Well, **if** there's already a `has` method, you'll be overwriting it. I'd probably have mentioned that. Anyway, jbabey's link in comment explains it very well. See also [Don't modify objectos you don't own](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/03/02/maintainable-javascript-dont-modify-objects-you-down-own/)

Comment: Bummer, it looks like I can't use the new String() in this case. The string is coming from Node's `fs.readFileSync(filePath, 'utf-8')` method which reads a file and returns a string. Since it's just going to be a command line program I guess the chance of a collision is slim.

Comment: Why can't you do something like `str = new MyStringDecorator(fs.readFileSync(filePath, 'utf-8'))` ?

Answer (score 0):

Consider this case:
You create this module, it's very useful so you put it up on NPM and many people use it. Some of these users also thought that extending the string object would be useful to them and they also called one of their methods "has".

When they use your module it overwrites their "has" method with yours. No worries as you'll clean up after yourself and delete the method you added. You know what happens next... they try to use their method and suddenly it's undefined!

If you name it something really obscure, it's pretty unlikely that you'll run into this but it's still not the best approach. Generally, it's best to try to keep your code as well encapsulated within the module as possible and avoid leaks.

In this case you may want to create your own string constructor that you could use and extend with custom methods to your heart's content without worrying about leaking your enhancements outside of the module.